# Iterating an Array by an Array (Another Ruby Word Count)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Having some trouble figuring out the logic for a ruby word count. My goal is to pass in some text, and get the total count of a certain category of words as defined in an array. So if I gave the following variables, I'd want to find out the fraction of words mentioned that have anything to do with fruit:

```
content = "I went to the store today, and I bought apples, eggs, bananas,
yogurt, bacon, spices, milk, oranges, and a pineapple. I also had a fruit 
smoothie and picked up some replacement Apple earbuds."

fruit = ["apple", "banana", "fruit", "kiwi", "orange", "pear", "pineapple", "watermelon"]
```

(I realize plural/singular is not consistent; just an example). Here's the code I've been trying:

```
content.strip
contentarray = content.downcase.split(/[^a-zA-Z]/)
contentarray.delete("")
total_wordcount = contentarray.size
```

IRB Test:

```
contentarray.grep("and")
=> ["and", "and", "and"]
contentarray.grep("and").count
=> 3
```

So then I try:

```
fruit.each do |i|
    contentarray.grep(i).count
end
=> ["apple", "banana", "fruit", "kiwi", "orange", "pear", "pineapple", "watermelon"]
```

It just returns the array, no counts. I would add them all up after if it returned any numbers. The goal is to end up with:

```
fruitwordcount 
=> 6 / 33
```

or

```
=> .1818181
```

I've tried searching and found a lot of methods saying to convert the content array to a hash count occurrences as many tutorials do, but that gives the count of every single word when I need the counts of only a subset. I can't seem to find a good way to search an array or string of words by an array of strings. I found a few articles saying to use a histogram from the Multiset gem, but that's still giving every word. Any help would be very much appreciated; please forgive my n00bery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are looking for is `map`, not `each`: [`each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) executes the block for each element in the array, and then returns the original array. [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) creates a new array containing the values returned by the block.

```
fruit.map do |i|
    contentarray.grep(i).count
end
=> [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Works like a champ. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[`Fruit#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) just iterates the fruits, while you likely want to collect value. [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) comes to the rescue:

```
result = fruit.map do |i|
    [i, contentarray.grep(i).count]
end
```

Whether you need a hash of `fruit ⇒ count`, it’s simple:

```
result = Hash[result]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `each` method just iterates and executes the block. Use `map` or `collect` to execute the block and return an array.

```
result = fruit.map { |i| counterarray.grep(i).count }
```

Answer (score 0):

array#each returns the array itself [as per ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each).

You probably want to try to give some of the other methods a try. Especially [count](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-count) and [map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) look promising:

```
fruit.map do |f|
  contentarray.count{|content| content == f}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To get just the fruits get your array - `contentarray.keep_if{|x| fruit.include?(x) }` then turn it into a hash count in the way you've found tutorials do.

Or just use inject on the `contentarray` to build the hash

```
contentarray.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |result, element|
  if fruit.include?(element)
    result[element] += 1
  end
  result
end
```

`Hash.new(0)` sets the default value to 0 so we can just add one